# _x0020_ Not Working in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

so I have 8 different SharePoint lists I am pulling from. And for aesthetic purposes I want to change the listname from something like "Program1" to "Program 1" as it doesn't change the url path to requesting the list. But when my code runs, and executes the AJAX, the 5 lists where I have yet to change the name still pull through, but the 3 I changed do not pull through. I even made sure to put the Program_x0020_1 and nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a stupid question. Sorry I figured it out. In the api url for the GET Request just put a space instead of the %20.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('x Deliverables')/items?
```